# Oracle flashback table reset

Tags: oracle, reset, flashback

Is there a way in Oracle to check with a sql (pl/sql) statement if a table is reset by a user?

Comment: Can you define "reset"?  That's not a term that reasonably applies to a table.

Comment: Sorry, reset should mean to return the table to a past state

Comment: What, exactly, constitutes "returning a table to a past state"?  If I insert a row and rollback my transaction, is that "returning a table to a past state"?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: This is what i mean :-) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr003.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the data dictionary that will tell you whether a `FLASHBACK TABLE` operation was ever performed on a table.  The `ROW_MOVEMENT` column of `DBA_TABLES` (or `ALL_TABLES` or `USER_TABLES` depending on your requirements and privileges) will tell you whether row movement is currently enabled which would allow someone to do a `FLASHBACK TABLE`.

Comment: Ok... Do you know if information to other flashback operation like flashback transaction query or flashback query are saved somewhere in the data dictonary?

Comment: @user2073471 - No, they are not.